# Drawing a bounding box around UI Elements in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bounding

I'm attempting to get the pixel-perfect bounding box for multiple UI elements in my scene, ensuring there are no empty spaces around the sprites. Is it possible to achieve this without checking for each individual pixel?

```
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    var min = Vector3.positiveInfinity;
    var max = Vector3.negativeInfinity;

    foreach (var image in imageList)
    {
        if(!image) continue;

        // Get the 4 corners in world coordinates
        var v = new Vector3[4];
        image.rectTransform.GetWorldCorners(v);

        // update min and max
        foreach (var vector3 in v)
        {
            min = Vector3.Min(min, vector3);
            max = Vector3.Max(max, vector3);
        }
        
    }
    // create the bounds
    var bounds = new Bounds();
    bounds.SetMinMax(min, max);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(bounds.center, bounds.extents*2);
}
```

This code produces the red box in this image below. But, what I'm after is the yellow box.

[image]
[image]

(Sprites are generated by user)

Comment: How important is performance here? ^^ Worst case: iterate the pixels and calculate minMax positions of the pixels that are not transparent ... will of course be insanely slow - but hyper precise ^^

Comment: For operations like this you don't want to have raw unprocessed images at hand. I am not sure if converting image to `Sprite` can help you. I guess sprites are designed for stuff like this, to perform more accurate hit-testing and not just by using rectangular bounds. But at least it should be possible to attach your own script, which run once to build shape and then you can to example use raycast to find bounds of transformed objects).

Comment: @derHugo this works on mobile so its kind a important. Also i generate sprites at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add PolygonCollider2D on them, and configure editor time. Then at the runtime, you can create new Bounds, and get bounds of all colliders [Collider2D.Bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-bounds.html), and use [Bounds.Encapsulate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Encapsulate.html).

P.S. I am not sure if will it work for a UI Element...

Comment: PolygonCollider2D will not work on UI elements. Also i generate sprites at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the images RectTransform to get the position and sizeDeltas.  Then use those to construct the bounds.

```
public class UIBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image[] images;

    private void Start()
    {
        var parent = images[0].transform.parent;
        var bounds = new Bounds(
            images[0].rectTransform.position, 
            images[0].rectTransform.sizeDelta
        );

        for (int i = 1; i < images.Length; i++)
        {
            bounds.Encapsulate(
                new Bounds(
                    images[i].rectTransform.position, 
                    images[i].rectTransform.sizeDelta
                )
            );
        }

        var newImage = new GameObject("Bounds Image").AddComponent<Image>();

        newImage.rectTransform.SetParent(parent);
        newImage.rectTransform.SetAsFirstSibling();
        newImage.rectTransform.position = bounds.center;
        newImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = bounds.size;
    }
}
```

The bounds are constructed using the first image of the array, then encapsulating all other images bounds.  (this prevents the origin point from being included in the bounds creation.

I added a new image to visualize the bounds created by the above code:

[image]

The resulting bounds is quite rudimentary, and will not work in all cases.  The above was tested with a square image+sprite.  Long rectangles or sprites that extend to all edges of the image will likely be cut off.

To get perfect bounds, you would need to sample the pixels of the source and handle the rotations.